# Unable to resolve a directory path error in Python

Tags: python, html, json, csv

I have a code which should convert all the HTML files to JSON and then is supposed to write it to a CSV file. However I am getting a directory error. Kindly let me know suggested changes, it does is a trivial problem but I am unable to resolve it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from os import listdir
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
import fnmatch
import shelve
import json
import csv


class College:
    def __init__(self, name, college, recognition, address, phone, fax, email, website):
        if name is None:
    name = ''
        if college is None:
    college = ''
        if recognition is None:
    recognition = ''
        if address is None:
    address = ''
        if phone is None:
    phone = ''
        if fax is None:
    fax = ''
        if email is None:
    email = ''
        if website is None:
    website = ''
        self.name = name
        self.college = college
        self.recognition = recognition
        self.address = address
        self.phone = phone
        self.fax = fax
        self.email = email
        self.website = website
        self.courses = []

    def to_json(self):
          return json.dumps(self, default=lambda o: o.__dict__,
                  sort_keys=True, indent=4)


class Course:
         def __init__(self, college_name, course_title, course_type,
                 course_duration, course_nature, qualifications,
                 brief_details, selection_process, course_branch, no_of_seats):
            if college_name is None:
                college_name = ''
            if course_title is None:
                course_title = ''
            if course_type is None:
                course_type = ''
            if course_duration is None:
                course_duration = ''
            if course_nature is None:
                course_nature = ''
            if qualifications is None:
                qualifications = ''
            if brief_details is None:
                brief_details = ''
            if selection_process is None:
                selection_process = ''
            if course_branch is None:
                selection_process = ''
            if no_of_seats is None:
                no_of_seats = ''

            self.college_name = college_name
            self.course_title = course_title
            self.course_type = course_type
            self.course_duration = course_duration
            self.course_nature = course_nature
            self.qualifications = qualifications
            self.brief_details = brief_details
            self.selection_process = selection_process
            self.course_branch = course_branch
            self.no_of_seats = no_of_seats
           # self.file_name = file_name


def get_colleges(file):
    Colleges = []
    fax = ''
    phone = ''
    address = ''
    email = ''
    website = ''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(open(file).read(), 'html.parser')
    table = soup.body.find('table', attrs={'class': 'text'})
    rows = table.find_all('tr', attrs={'onmouseover': "this.className='pa-row-highlight'"})

   for name in rows:
       td = name.find_all('td')
       collegename = td[0].find('span', attrs={'class': 'text1'}).text
college = td[0].find('i')
       if college is not None:
            college = college.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')
recognition = td[0].find('b')
       if recognition is not None and recognition.next_sibling is not None:
           recognition = recognition.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

           td2s = td[1].find_all('b')
           for item in td2s:
               if item is not None:
                   if item.text.upper().find('ADDRESS') != -1:
                       address = item.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

                   if item.text.upper().find('TEL') != -1:
                       phone = item.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

                  if item.text.upper().find('FAX') != -1:
                      fax = item.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

                  if item.text.upper().find('WEBSITE') != -1:
                      website = item.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

                  if item.text.upper().find('EMAIL') != -1:
                      email = item.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

            Colleges.append(College(collegename, college, recognition, address, phone, fax, email, website))
        return Colleges


def new_write_file(file, colleges):
    json_strs = []
    for college in colleges:
        json_str = college.to_json()
        json_str = json_str.replace('\u00a0', '')
        json_strs.append(json_str)

    i = 0
    len_json_strs = len(json_strs) - 1
    f = open(file, 'w')
    f.write('[')
    for string1 in json_strs:
        f.write(string1)
        if i != len_json_strs:
            f.write(',')
        i += 1

    f.write(']')
    f.close()


def write_csv(read_file_path):
    data = json.loads(open(read_file_path).read())
    file_colleges = csv.writer(open(r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/colleges.csv', 'w', newline=''))
    list_colleges_headers = ['name', 'college', 'recognition', 'address', 'phone', 'fax', 'email', 'website']
    file_colleges.writerow(list_colleges_headers)
    list_courses_headers = ['course_title', 'course_type', 'course_duration',
                    'course_nature', 'qualifications', 'brief_details', 'selection_process', 'course_branch',
                    'no_of_seats']
    for d in data:
        file_colleges.writerow(
    [d['name'], d['college'], d['recognition'], d['address'], d['phone'], d['fax'], d['fax'], d['website']])
        file_course = csv.writer(
        open(r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/courses_csv/' + d['name'].strip('"').replace('"', '') + '.csv', 'w', newline=''))
        file_course.writerow(list_courses_headers)
        for course in d['courses']:
            file_course.writerow(
                [
                 (course['course_title'] if course['course_title'] is not None or course[
                                                                              'course_title'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_type'] if course['course_type'] is not None or course['course_type'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_duration'] if course['course_duration'] is not None or course[
                                                                                    'course_duration'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_nature'] if course['course_nature'] is not None or course[
                                                                                'course_nature'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['qualifications'] if course['qualifications'] is not None or course[
                                                                                  'qualifications'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['brief_details'] if course['brief_details'] is not None or course[
                                                                                'brief_details'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['selection_process'] if course['selection_process'] is not None or course[
                                                                                        'selection_process'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['course_branch'] if course['course_branch'] is not None or course[
                                                                                'course_branch'] != '' else 'NA'),
                 (course['no_of_seats'] if course['no_of_seats'] is not None or course['no_of_seats'] != '' else 'NA')])
    pass


def write_file(file, colleges):
    db = shelve.open(file)
    for college in colleges:
        db[college.name] = college
        db.close()


def read_colleges(directoryPath=''):
    Colleges = []
    if directoryPath == '':
        directoryPath = os.getcwd()

    for file in listdir(directoryPath):
        filepath = os.path.join(directoryPath, file)
        if isfile(filepath) and fnmatch.fnmatch(filepath, '*.htm'):
            Colleges = Colleges + get_colleges(filepath)
    return Colleges


def get_courses(file):
    Courses = []
    college_name = ''
    course_title = ''
    course_type = ''
    course_duration = ''
    course_nature = ''
    qualifications = ''
    brief_details = ''
    selection_process = ''
    no_of_seats = 0
    course_branch = ''
    html_start = '''
          <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0  Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>SchoolColleges</title>
   /head>

  <body>
   '''
   html_end = '''
    </body>
   </html>
      '''
      table_end = '''
      </td></tr></table>
       '''
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_start + open(file).read().replace('</td></tr></table>', '') + table_end + html_end,
                 'html.parser')

    if soup.body is not None:
        table = soup.body.find('table', attrs={'class': 'text'})
    else:
        table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class': 'text'})

    if table is None:
        return Courses

    td_college = table.find('td', attrs={'class': 'text1'})

    if td_college is not None:
        college_name = td_college.text

        rows = soup.find_all('tr', recursive=True)

       for row in rows:

           add_course = False

           if row is None:
               continue
           # td = row.parent.find('b')
           all_block_quotes = row.parent.find_all('b')
          if all_block_quotes is None:
               continue

for b in all_block_quotes:
    if b is None:
        continue

    if b.text.upper().find('COURSE TYPE') != -1:
        course_type = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')
        course_branch = b.parent.parent.find('span').b.text.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    if b.text.upper().find('NO OF SEATS') != -1:
        no_of_seats = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    if b.text.upper().find('COURSE DURATION') != -1:
        course_duration = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    if b.text.upper().find('QUALIFICATION REQUIRED') != -1:
        qualifications = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    if b.text.upper().find('BRIEF DETAILS') != -1:
        brief_details = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    if b.text.upper().find('SELECTION PROCESS') != -1:
        selection_process = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    if b.text.upper().find('COURSE NATURE') != -1:
        course_nature = b.next_sibling.replace('&nbsp;', '')

    add_course = any([course_title, course_type,
                      course_duration, course_nature, qualifications,
                      brief_details, selection_process, no_of_seats])

    if add_course:
        Courses.append(Course(college_name, course_title, course_type,
                          course_duration, course_nature, qualifications,
                          brief_details, selection_process, course_branch, no_of_seats))
    return Courses


def read_courses(directoryPath=''):
    Courses = []
    if directoryPath == '':
        directoryPath = os.getcwd()
        for file in listdir(directoryPath):
            filepath = os.path.join(directoryPath, file)
            if isfile(filepath) and fnmatch.fnmatch(filepath, '*.htm'):
                Courses = Courses + get_courses(filepath)
        return Courses
read_file_path = r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com'
colleges = read_colleges(r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/colleges')
courses = read_courses(r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com/courses')

for college in colleges:
    college_courses = [course for course in courses if   course.college_name.upper() == college.name.upper()]
    college.courses = college_courses

new_write_file(r'/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com1 /college1', colleges)
write_csv(read_file_path)
enter code hereprint('done!!!')
```

Above is the code and below is the error.

```
maitreyee@Maitreyee:~/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com$ python html2csv2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "html2csv2.py", line 315, in <module>
    write_csv(read_file_path)
  File "html2csv2.py", line 147, in write_csv
    data = json.loads(open(read_file_path).read())
IOError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't open a directory. Since `/home/maitreyee/Downloads/SchoolCollege.com` is a directory, not a file, you need to open the files it contains one by one.